# ColdFusion Dropbox - How to get the token from the response URI

Tags: coldfusion, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to implement the OAuth with Dropbox from a ColdFusion application, and I managed how to call the Dropbox method to generate the access token, but... I don't know how to get the generated TOKEN from the response URI. I am getting something like this from Dropbox:

```
http://localhost/dropbox/generate_token.cfm#access_token=AAAAAAAAYVM_XdCYlbTz0gQOwQkWlg6TDXf84_5h4giikg6J-7Man&token_type=bearer&uid=267693&account_id=dbid%3AAABeDMm-BN0n1DofLZz9kPZAipnQ
```

How to I retrieve the URL variables in this case? I mean if I do a

```
<cfdump var="#URL#">
```

I am getting an empty struct. If I do a

```
<cfdump var="#CGI#">
```

I still don't see any of the URL retrieved parameters in the structure. How do I get the variables and their values from the Dropbox response?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

At some point I thought I found a way to read the URL but now - for no reason - this doesn't work anymore! I didn't change anything but the solution below doesn't work anymore.

I can read the full URL with JavaScript using `document.location` but this means to do an extra submit to a ColdFusion page and I don't want to do this. I want to get the Dropbox token from the URL and save it to the database directly in this page...

Any new ideas please?

---

SOLUTION THAT SEEMED TO WORK AT SOME POINT ...

I found a way to get the URI string using this:

```
<cfset objRequest = GetPageContext().GetRequest().getParameterMap() />

<cfdump var="#objRequest#">

<cfoutput>
<cfloop collection="#objRequest#" item="i">
    <p>
        #i# - #objRequest[i][1]#
    </p>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

From now on, I know how to get the values returned by Dropbox.

Comment: Unfortunately, for no reason, this is not working anymore! Now I am getting an empty structure again even I swear this worked before... Any ideas?

Comment: Which example in the API are you trying to implement? Can you post a link? Have not used it, but a quick search turned up [this doc](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide#oauth-2-on-the-web) but the process flow sounds different than what you are describing...

Comment: Yes, is exactly that method from the link you posted. The return from Dropbox is of that form: [your_set_uri] and Dropbox is appending "##access_token=.... and the rest of the parameters". My problem was parsing this URL to extract the returned token and other parameters.

Comment: *Dropbox is appending "##access_token=* That means it [will not be accessible in server side code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734612/getting-the-named-anchor-using-coldfusion). So as you discovered, javascript is your only option. Kind of weird though. I would have expected the callback to use regular parameters, so the response could be parsed from either JS or a server side language.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the returned parameters by reading the browser URL with JavaScript, so in two steps: **first**, parse and extract the full URL including the part after the # sign (I found this has a name and it is called the "URL fragment") and **second**, create a JavaScript form with parsed parameters and resubmitted to the server. Here is the code:

```
<cfparam name="FORM.action" default="">

<cfif FORM.action IS "save_token">

    <cfdump var="#FORM#">

<cfelse>

    <form name="main" id="main" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="save_token">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    <!--
        var parameters = window.location.hash.substr(1).split("&");

        function addHidden(theForm, key, value) {
            // Create a hidden input element, and append it to the form:
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "hidden";
            input.name = key;
            input.value = value;
            theForm.appendChild(input);
        }

        // Form reference:
        var theForm = document.forms["main"];

        for (var i=0; i<parameters.length; i++) {
            // Add data:
            addHidden(theForm, parameters[i].split("=")[0], parameters[i].split("=")[1]);
        }

        theForm.submit();
    //-->
    </script>

</cfif>
```